# try catch not always works in iced coffee script

Tags: error-handling, iced-coffeescript

I use `try catch` block in `iced coffee script`. I call not existent method `fake` of not existent object `a` and expect to catch error.

```
db = require '../../call/db.iced'
try
    await db.find "79", defer c, d
    a.fake()
catch error
    console.log "error catched"
    console.log error
```

But after calling function `db.find` a.fake() throw error in console, but it don't use `try catch` block as expected.

If I comment out string `await db.find "79", defer c, d`...

```
db = require '../../call/db.iced'
    try
        # await db.find "79", defer c, d ############## commented out
        a.fake()
    catch error
        console.log "error catched"
        console.log error
```

... it works as expected and error is catched.

I tried to change string `await db.find "79", defer c, d` by other simple async functions calles but they works fine and error was catched well.

It is interesting that function `db.find` works good. When I comment out string `a.fake()`...

```
db = require '../../call/db.iced'
    try
        await db.find "79", defer c, d
        #a.fake() ################################ commented out
    catch error
        console.log "error catched"
        console.log error
```

... this script works without any errors and so without catching errors.

Can not figure out why I can not catch error after function `await db.find "79", defer c, d`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation states](http://maxtaco.github.io/coffee-script/#iced_finish) the following on `try catch` statements:

> The only exception is `try`, which doesn't catch exceptions when called
>   from event handlers the main loop, for the same reason hand-rolled
>   asynchronous code and `try` do not work well together.

I suspect that since `db.find` is called asynchronously, the `try` construct remains with the `db.find` thread and does not stay in the main thread. This would result in the findings you describe.

One crude solution is to catch both function calls. However, I think the proper way to use `await` is with the `defer` function. [Check out the documentation for an explanation.](http://maxtaco.github.io/coffee-script/#iced_basics)

Also, you might find the following helpful:

- [How to correctly handle errors with IcedCoffeeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322083/how-to-correctly-handle-errors-with-icedcoffeescript)

**Possible Solutions**

1. Place a try catch around both statements.

   ```
   try
       await db.find "79", defer c, d
   catch error
       console.log "error catched"
       console.log error
   try
       a.fake()
   catch error
       console.log "error catched"
       console.log error
   ```
2. [As described in the link above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322083/how-to-correctly-handle-errors-with-icedcoffeescript), place `db.find` outside the try catch and detect it's error another way.

   ```
   await db.find "79", defer err, id
   if err then return cb err, null

   try
       a.fake()
   catch error
       console.log "error catched"
       console.log error
   ```

Comment: Thank you! And how should I change try catch block to catch error on `a.fake()` call? Or the single way is to exclude async functions from `try` block?

Comment: Added some solutions to my answer. See if that helps.